# Cannot find a document in the list

Tags: wss-3.0

I am not able to find a document in the list but I am able to access the document if I am typing the whole URL

Can access it through like : http://www.abc.com/myfiles/doc1.xsl

But when I am opening myfiles document library I am not able to see that document.

Thanks
RHM

Comment: Is it in a meeting workspace ? Do you see it using WebDav ?

Comment: WebDav ? You mean SharePoint Designer 2007 ... if so.. No I cannot see it in SharePoint Designer 07

Comment: I mean using the explorer view. And please, tell me if it's in a meeting workspace.

Comment: Are you sure that the view doesn't hide the document? or a check-out file?

Comment: Nope, it is not something with the view ... I think